# What is the difference between shuffle and random_shuffle c++

Tags: c++, c++11, std

The function [std::shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) has been introduced in C++11:

```
template< class RandomIt, class URNG >
void shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, URNG&& g );
```

and it has the same signature as one of the overloads of [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) which was also introduced in C++11:

```
template< class RandomIt, class RandomFunc >
void random_shuffle( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, RandomFunc&& r );
```

The difference is in the third parameter where:

> URNG must meet the requirements of UniformRandomNumberGenerator

Is this all? Is the difference just that `shuffle` performs an extra compile time check? Is the behavior otherwise the same?

Comment: Btw, in the standard "X must meet the requirements of Y" doesn't mean that the implementation checks it. It means that behavior is undefined if X fails to meet the requirements of Y. In any template code there will be some compile-time checking, but usually only of the parts of interface Y that the implementation actually uses.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you read the documentation at cppreference.com closely, you will find that the `RandomFunc` passed to `random_shuffle` has a **different interface**. It is invoked as `r(n)`. This existed before C++11.

`std::shuffle` uses a standardized way of getting random numbers and invokes `g()`. This standardized random number generators where introduced with C++11 together with `std::shuffle`.

Comment: +1, and `<random>` was a long-time-coming and I'm thoroughly glad it did. I was in the process of writing this up,sample code and all, but your brief covered it nicely. Note: `r(n)` returns a number between 0 and (n-1).

Answer (score 22):

`std::random_shuffle` uses `std::rand()` function to randomize the items, while the `std::shuffle` uses `urng` which is a better random generator, though with the particular overload of `std::random_shuffle`, you can get the same behavior (as with the `std::shuffle`) but that requires you to do some work to pass the third argument.

Watch this talk by Stephan T. Lavavej, in which he explains why `std::rand` is a bad function and what C++ programmers should use instead:

- [rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

The gist is, `std::shuffle` is an improvement over `std::random_shuffle`, and C++ programmers should prefer using the former.

Comment: Not if you use the overload specified in the question. In that case it uses `r` as the random number generator.

Comment: But what about the particular overload that I posted. Does that one use std::rand somewhere inside?

Comment: @MartinDrozdik It *can* (and the default *does*).

Comment: @WhozCraig: No it **can't**. The overload mentioned in the questions takes a function object and is defined to use that as it's source of randomness by the standard.

Comment: @Grizzly read that again. The ***default*** does. I never said the default-provider **is** `std::rand()`. I said it **does** *use* it. Regarding the overload, whether "it" (i.e. the overload) does is entirely up to the provider (you), and thus it ***can***.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: I didn't notice that you were talking about the overload which takes third argument. Anyway, I updated by answer.

Comment: +1 and the real gist is `<random>` is the absolute cats pajamas and heads-and-tails better than `rand()`.

Comment: `std::random_shuffle` uses the random source you pass it, and some implementation defined source if you don't pass it one.  It doesn't necessarily use `std::rand()`.  And `std::rand()` isn't necessarily a bad function; it's just not guaranteed to be a good one.

Comment: @JamesKanze The C standard has a footnote: "There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations
are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with
particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufﬁcient for their needs." That's a pretty strong Caveat Emptor IMHO.

Comment: @TemplateRex Caveat Emptor, certainly.  I wouldn't use it in a context were I needed any real guarantees, and I'd be hesitant about using it in anything which was supposed to be portable.  But I've used it successfully in many cases in the past.  You just have to be aware of its limitations (...or be doing something like a school project, where they really don't matter at all).

Comment: @JamesKanze In any case, `rand()` will be deprecated in C++14 so that should settle it, even for school projects.

Comment: @TemplateRex: The deprecation of `rand()` was discussed at the Oct. 2013 meeting in Chicago.  The proposal gained enough momentum to make it to the formal motions page.  However it was so controversial that the motion was pulled without an official vote  on it.  "Will be deprecated" is something no one can say at this point.  There is a possibility that it could be deprecated in C++14.  However if I had to bet money one way or another, I'd put my money on it not being deprecated in C++14.

Comment: @HowardHinnant tnx for setting that straight.