# How to randomly insert numbers from 1 to 5 into a vector and check to make sure there is no duplicate?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a novice programmer and would like some help on a particular task I have been facing for days. I know this task seem's basic but my task is to insert random integers from 1 to 5 into a vector that can hold at least 5 elements. However, I need to make sure that there are no duplicates found. This part of the program has troubled me. Can anyone please explain to me what they would do conceptually or code wise? Thank you.

Comment: You should preferably use `std::set`.

Comment: It would be nice to use a vector

Comment: Insert the numbers 1..5, then shuffle the array.  `std::shuffle` with a decently prepared rng would do it easily.

Comment: That is one possible solution. Thank you for your insight :)

Comment: And fyi, rereading your question, if the numbers cannot have duplicates and consist of number 1 to 5, then your container that, "can hold *at least 5 elements*" had better not hold any more than five, or you've violated your first condition (must consist of numbers 1 to 5).

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the vector with the values [1..5] and then shuffle it:

```
std::vector<int> mem = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::random_shuffle ( std::begin(mem), std::end(mem) );
```

**Edit**

`std::shuffle` was introduced in c++11 and considered to be more preferable over `std::random_shufle`. The usage in this example is the same. For more info regarding the differences please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219726/what-is-the-difference-between-shuffle-and-random-shuffle-c).

Comment: `std::shuffle` is recommended over `std::random_shuffle`

Comment: @milleniumbug, not critical for this example I think but I will EDIT it. Thank you.